# Why is Internet traffic being blocked for .NET programs ONLY?

Tags: .net, winforms, service, web

We have a POS-based application in Windows Forms written in VB.NET, which we're rolling out to franchise stores - 70, so far.

The application replicates data by means of a connection to a head office server: all communication is by means of Web Services (upload & download).

All is working really well, except - you knew it was coming  - on literally a handful of stores we cannot connect to the web services, although we know that the Internet service is good!

Here's a bullet-point summary of the situation:

1. in this handful of stores, ALL .NET (only) internet traffic fails on this POS computer.
2. primarily this traffic is using port 80 to connect to web services, using SOAP (standard)
3. BUT they can successfully use a browser in the POS to see web pages;  also, a test program I created in Clarion (straight Win 32) also connects to the web service ok.
4. In addition, an associated data conversion app (again in VB.NET) also fails when trying to connect to MS SQL at HQ (and only for this handful of stores).
   Note: this uses a standard ADO connection, thus a completely different protocol to the above.
5. So it's just all .NET Internet that fails... different apps, different protocol.
   The error message in all cases is "The operation has timed out"
   Note: timeout is set to 15 seconds - ample time for simple web service, esp. as the initial method is just a time-check.
6. Take a POS that's failing to connect and move to a different site: all good
7. Take a POS that's failing to connect and change the router: all good
8. But the routers in failing stores are *not* all the same

It looks as if the .NET setup on the POS pc is somehow being 'blocked'.

Too weird - what am I missing here?

Grateful for pointers... I'm stumped!
Steve.

---

EDIT: I used the word 'router' - should more accurately have been modem/router.
For info, here's a sample of gear used in the few 'problem' stores:

- 2 x NetGear N300 Wireless ADSL2+  Modem Router DGN2200v3
- DSL-2642B Wireless G54 ADSL2+  Modem Router
- NetGear N600 Wireless Dual Band Gigabit ADSL2+  Modem Router DGND3700v2

Wired connection is used for POS terminal, of course.

S.

Comment: Maybe is is something that is being cached on the router.

Comment: Are all clients the same version of Windows? Are the stores on same domain as hq and sql/iis web services? How are you rolling the Windows client out to stores? Automated or remotely or a non ict technician on site? I.e. are they definitely following the installation instructions correctly? Is there anything in the event viewer on the client? Is it being blocked by the firewall on client? Is the connections to IIS web services restricted to some static ips of the client? Have they recently changed? Can you use fiddler on the client to check for any errors?

Comment: Is is just http port 80 traffic and/or https 443 assuming default ports? Why the difference in configuration?

Comment: Also if you open IE on the windows client can you access the endpoint url? If not maybe configure auto proxy o connection settings in IE

Comment: What error message do you get when you "cannot connect"?

Comment: Blam: perhaps... you have anything specific in mind?

Comment: Kyle: O/S is the POS version of XP, supplied by the (same) supplier; i.e. all machines from the same supplier. 
Not on same domain.... completely open slather (like a  home internet installation). 
Installations all done manually by the *one* trusted, pedantic person, via remote log-in... following same protocol. 
Firewall twice-checked: also, point #3 covers that. 
Nothing installed to restrict IIS web service - again point #3 covers that (Clarion app *can* connect).

Comment: Kyle: Some stores have recently installed this new router as part of the rollout/upgrade, others have had it for a while. But the 'old' system did not use either .NET or web services, so didn't come up. Going to use Fiddler when I log in tomorrow and have a poke around.
Was hoping to get a few ideas from this forum to check!

Comment: Kyle: I have only tried 80 (HTTP) & 1433 (SQL), standard ports.. as described in the post in points #2 & #4.
Not sure what you mean by 'difference in configuration'?

Comment: Kyle: using IE to connect to the web sites at those URLs is on my list of 'stuff to try' when I log in tomorrow.
My *expectation* (based on teh evidence to this point) is that they will be successful - because it is only .NET traffic being blocked.

Comment: Look at the proxy settings of IE. Maybe IE is configured to use an Internet proxy and the .NET code is not.

Comment: John: interesting thought - its the first thing that might even be possible <g>. 
I would have thought it unlikely - don't know who would have set up a proxy on their IE. I believe these are mostly new machines, supposedly all produced from the same system image by the manufacturer.
In addition - how would that explain the ability of the Clarion app to connect?
But I will check tomorrow, when I log in.

Comment: Are there any network related settings in your app.config? Fiddler should be able to check if any http requests are issued, and what happens to them. Could there be old router software not handling the "Expect: 100 Continue" header? That can be disabled with `<servicePointManager expect100Continue="false"/>`.

Comment: Simon: currently there is *no* app.config in the production installation.
The destination URL (for web service) is quite involved, involving querystring obfuscation - is all coded into the .NET proxy, and I  desired no app.config.
(I did use it for 'local' Fiddler checking - will do so again tomorrow when I remote-in to use Fiddler at the store.)

And the SQL data converter app (being admin use only) has user & password entry - again no app.config used.

Note your comment re "expect 100".... however this is NEW modem routers we are talking about here. Couldn't we assume no 'old software'?

Comment: Simon: Yeah, yeah...all that I said - but I will *definitely* try turning "Expect: 100 Continue" off <G>   Tx for the tip!

Comment: In IE Options check out the HTTP settings and try the opposite.  I mean literally the opposite.  I had a case where some clients would work on one setting and others on the other.

Comment: Update: tested one store last night: checked no IE Proxy set; turned off "Expect 100 Continue", installed Fiddler, and noticed that header had gone. But no effect on comms. Then I noticed that despite Timeout message, the HTTP *had* returned a valid response (in Fiddler). So I lengthened the timeout... and it responds ok!  Noted that the connection time for a simple UTC time check web service call is > 15 seconds - so something weird is going on - but I wasn't exactly told the truth about the situation!!!

Comment: At this point I'm saying "you're Internet is too slow"...(am I wrong?).
I do need to check another 'problem' store though - could be different things going on.

Comment: s/be ...."*your* Internet..."